# CMake: Is there a way to make just a part from the OpenCV libraries?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I want to use just 4 from the `OpenCV` libraries, and I have build it all on my computer, but on the other one, I want to build just the 4 of them. Is there a way to do it with `CMake`? Shall I modify the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file? If yes, how?

Or to be more precisely, the question is:

**How to build the `OpenCV`s libraries one by one?** using Linux

Comment: If you use cmake-gui, there are check boxes next to each module. You can uncheck all the ones you don't need to build only specific modules.

Comment: Yes, that is on Windows, but I use Linux. Updating question

Comment: cmake-gui works on Linux too. On Ubuntu, you can install with `sudo apt-get install cmake-qt-gui`, and run with `cmake-gui`. Other distros should be similar.